# Geometric distribution, can this approach be correct?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am revising and came upon these questions, but I am not sure if the answers are right especially for part B

Suppose the probability of defective is p(D) = 0.009 , p(d^c)=0.991
and mean 7 and std = 1.5

A) Suppose you select one battery at a time from the manufacturer, what is the probability that the first defective batery is found in the fourth selection?

Answer: 3(0.0099) * (0.991)^3 = 0.026

B)Suppose you select one battery at a time from the manufacturer, what is the probability that the third defective battery is found in the tenth selection?

Answer: will be 9(0.0099)^3 * (0.991)^7 =0.000

Comment: mean and std of what? Btw, if the probability on being defective if 0.009 then the probability on not being defective is 1-0.009=0.991.

Comment: The probability that the first defective battery is found in the fourth selection corresponds to the event that the first battery is good, the second battery is good, the third battery is good, and the fourth battery is defective.  This would simply be $0.0099\cdot 0.9901^3$.  Your attempt has an extra coefficient of $3$ which is unnecessary.  As for part (B), within the first nine selections, exactly two will be defective, so by taking into account which positions those are you will have a coefficient of $\binom{9}{2}$, not a coefficient of $9$ as in your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p = \text{Pr}(D)$.

A) First 3 should not be defective and fourth should be defective, by product rule the probability of this happening is $(1-p)^{3} p$.

B) First there should be 2 out of 9 defective which can happen in ${9}\choose{2}$ ways and 10th one defective, so probability is ${9}\choose{2}$ $p^{3} (1-p)^{7}$.

Comment: Suppose that chips are inspected one by one, what is the probability the second defective chips was found in the 7th inspection trial? while say p(d) = 0.1 ------- -----         Here the asnwer will be : 6 * 0.1^2 * 0.9^5  but in our answer it was 9C2? while here its 6C1?

Comment: so it it like 9C(picks -1) right?